# How can I create an object that stores data.frames, and allows one to retrieve them with '.'?

Tags: r

Often times, when I'm using different 3rd party functions, said functions will return some useful data structure that stores a lot of data that I can retrieve with `.`. Let's say, for example, I'd like to return two data frames, `Red` and `Blue`.

I'd like for the user to be able to do something like:

```
stuff <- this_nice_function()
stuff.Red$column_name
stuff.Blue$column_name
```

As a bonus, if said user were to just write `stuff` into the console, I'd like an output like...

```
This contains two data.frames, Red and Blue. 
Red is size [x]. Blue is size [y]
Available fields: Red, Blue
```

(Or something like this, similar to the output of `dbscan`)

I've looked around quite a bit, but the `.` related threads are focused on the usage of `.` in a function argument.

Comment: The way to do this in R is with lists. So you'd get `stuff$Red$column_name`. For print methods, you can use the S3 class system. Assign a class, and define a print method for that class.

Comment: `.` is not an operator in R. It is just a character that you can use in variable names. It has no real special meaning. So `stuff.Red` isn't all related to `stuff` (unless you consider the very special case of S3 method dispatch but it doesn't seem like that's what you are doing here). Are you trying to use object oriented code in R? Maybe check out an overview on the object oriented options in R: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html#oop-systems Maybe you want S4 style slots, but those use `@` rather than `.`